# How to dynamically update batch norm momentum in TF2?

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch, tensorflow2.0, batch-normalization, momentum

I found a PyTorch implementation that decays the batch norm `momentum` parameter from `0.1` in the first epoch to `0.001` in the final epoch. Any suggestions on how to do this with the batch norm `momentum` parameter in TF2? (i.e., start at `0.9` and end at `0.999`) For example, this is what is done in the PyTorch code:

```
# in training script
momentum = initial_momentum * np.exp(-epoch/args.epochs * np.log(initial_momentum/final_momentum))
model_pos_train.set_bn_momentum(momentum)

# model class function
def set_bn_momentum(self, momentum):
    self.expand_bn.momentum = momentum
    for bn in self.layers_bn:
        bn.momentum = momentum
```

**SOLUTION:**

The selected answer below provides a viable solution when using the `tf.keras.Model.fit()` API. However, I was using a custom training loop. Here is what I did instead:

After each epoch:

```
mi = 1 - initial_momentum  # i.e., inital_momentum = 0.9, mi = 0.1
mf = 1 - final_momentum  # i.e., final_momentum = 0.999, mf = 0.001
momentum = 1 - mi * np.exp(-epoch / epochs * np.log(mi / mf))
model = set_bn_momentum(model, momentum)
```

set_bn_momentum function (credit to [this article](https://sthalles.github.io/keras-regularizer/)):

```
def set_bn_momentum(model, momentum):
    for layer in model.layers:
        if hasattr(layer, 'momentum'):
            print(layer.name, layer.momentum)
            setattr(layer, 'momentum', momentum)

    # When we change the layers attributes, the change only happens in the model config file
    model_json = model.to_json()

    # Save the weights before reloading the model.
    tmp_weights_path = os.path.join(tempfile.gettempdir(), 'tmp_weights.h5')
    model.save_weights(tmp_weights_path)

    # load the model from the config
    model = tf.keras.models.model_from_json(model_json)

    # Reload the model weights
    model.load_weights(tmp_weights_path, by_name=True)
    return model
```

This method did not add significant overhead to the training routine.

Comment: It's not clear what you up to. Can you show pytorch code precisely that does what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set an action in the begin/the end of each batch, so you can control the any parameter during the epoch.

Below the options for the callbacks:

```
class CustomCallback(keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def on_epoch_begin(self, epoch, logs=None):
        keys = list(logs.keys())
        print("Start epoch {} of training; got log keys: {}".format(epoch, keys))

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
        keys = list(logs.keys())
        print("End epoch {} of training; got log keys: {}".format(epoch, keys))

    def on_train_batch_begin(self, batch, logs=None):
        keys = list(logs.keys())
        print("...Training: start of batch {}; got log keys: {}".format(batch, keys))

    def on_train_batch_end(self, batch, logs=None):
        keys = list(logs.keys())
        print("...Training: end of batch {}; got log keys: {}".format(batch, keys))

    def on_test_batch_begin(self, batch, logs=None):
        keys = list(logs.keys())
        print("...Evaluating: start of batch {}; got log keys: {}".format(batch, keys))

    def on_test_batch_end(self, batch, logs=None):
        keys = list(logs.keys())
        print("...Evaluating: end of batch {}; got log keys: {}".format(batch, keys))
```

You can access the momentum

```
batch = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()
batch.momentum = 0.001
```

Inside the model you have to specified the correct layer

```
model.layers[1].momentum = 0.001
```

You can find more information and example at [writing_your_own_callbacks](https://keras.io/guides/writing_your_own_callbacks/)

Comment: Thanks. Do you know how to access the batch norm momentum parameter of your model, or better yet specific layers, in the callback?

Comment: I guess you can access through `self.model.layers`

Comment: Sorry I've read momentum but I've written learning rate, I've update my answer